# What is the derivative of the function $s(t)=(1-e^{\frac{-t}{RC}})u(t)$?

Tags: derivatives

What is the derivative of the following function

$$s(t)=(1-e^{\frac{-t}{RC}})u(t)$$

with respect to $t$, where $u(t)$ is a unit step function?

I am getting $$\delta(t)+\frac{1}{RC}e^{-t/RC}u(t)$$ as the answer.

Is my answer correct?

Answer (score 1):

I get 
\begin{align*}
\dot{s}(t)&=\frac{d}{dt}\left[\left(1-\exp\left(-\frac{t}{RC}\right)\right)u(t)\right] \\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\,u(t)-\frac{d}{dt}\left[\exp\left(-\frac{t}{RC}\right)u(t)\right]\\
&=\delta(t)-\underbrace{\left[-\frac{1}{RC}\,\exp\left(-\frac{t}{RC}\right)u(t)+\exp\left(-\frac{t}{RC}\right)\delta(t)\right]}_{\text{Don't forget the product rule!}} \\
&=\left(1-\exp\left(-\frac{t}{RC}\right)\right)\delta(t)+\frac{1}{RC}\,\exp\left(-\frac{t}{RC}\right)u(t).
\end{align*}

Comment: Sir, $\delta (t)$ is defined only at $t=0$. So can the above expression reduce to: 

$$(1-e^{-\frac{-0}{RC}})\delta(0)+\frac{1}{RC}e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}u(t)$$
$$=(1-1)\delta(0)+\frac{1}{RC}e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}u(t)$$
$$=\frac{1}{RC}e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}u(t)$$

Comment: Sir the function $s(t)=(1-e^{\frac{-t}{RC}})u(t)$ is discontinious at $t=0$. So should the derivative at $t=0$ exist?

Comment: $\delta(t)$ is a distribution, so when we write that $\dfrac{d}{dt}\,u(t)=\delta(t)$, we mean it in the distribution sense. $\delta(t)$ is defined in the distribution sense everywhere. Your working is invalid, because the delta function is thought of as infinite at the origin. What you're thinking of can only be done inside an integral. This sort of answers your other question as well. The derivative of the step function is *formally* the delta function.